# How to create folders inside a custom album in photos app in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, photosframework, alassetlibrary

I want to create a custom album " My Album" in the photos app in iphone. Inside "My Album" I need two sub albums/folders "Media" and "Web". 
   I am able to create custom album. Is it possible to create folders inside a custom album? 
   If yes then how to create, save and retrieve images/videos from it? I prefer the codes in objective c. Thanks in advance.